# Why does firebase.initializeApp not work?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I've basically copy and pasted the exact code from the firebase documentation on how to set up firestore. When I try to run my, app, I get a breaking error, which says my app has not been initialized.

here is my firebase.js config file:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { fbConfig } from "./secrets.js"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: fbConfig.apiKey,
  authDomain: fbConfig.authDomain,
  projectId: fbConfig.projectId,
  storageBucket: fbConfig.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: fbConfig.messagingSenderId,
  appId: fbConfig.appId
});

console.log(firebaseApp)
export default getFirestore()
```

For comparison, [here is a link to the firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize).
My console log is returning this:

```
FirebaseAppImpl {_isDeleted: false, _options: {…}, _config: {…}, _name: '[DEFAULT]', _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false, …}
{...}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Here is the code where firebase is being called, in a different file:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import db from "../firebase" 
//I'm expecting db to be my exported firestore call from firebase.js

function Admin() {
  const onFormSubmit = async (data) => {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "interviewees", data.name), {
      name: data.name,
      location: data.location,
      age: data.age,
    });
  };

  return(<a big component>)
}
```

When the Admin component renders, this error appears:

> errors.ts:91 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

so, it looks to my like there is an app being initialized. But my app crashing and the error message seems to disagree with my assessment. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: First fbConfig are not secret they are just paths to connect to your database.

Comment: Is the error silenced when you pass the app in explicitly? `getFirestore(firebaseApp)`

Comment: There is not enough information here.  We can't see how the code that throws this error is being run in relation to your firebase.js.  Please edit the question to show the line of code that actually generates the error, and how that executes in relation to firebase.js.

Comment: @samthecodingman no, instead I just get this error: Uncaught Error: Service firestore is not available

Comment: @DougStevenson please see my updated question! Thanks to your comment, I was able to remove some unnecessary code from the file that is generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return db not called function like `export default getFirestore()`

```js
const firebaseApp = initializeApp({...});

const db = getFirestore() // In this line function are assigning database to a variable.

export { db }
```

Example of usage db:

```js
import { addDoc, collection } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from '...../firebase.js' // change path to your file

function addDocument(path, data) {
   addDoc(collection(db, path), data)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just had to delete my node modules and package log and npm install...